# Understand cmd command which runs java application

Tags: java, cmd

I have the following code in the batch:

> "C:/EDI_Module/jre1.8.0_121/bin/java" -Xms2g -Xmx10g -cp .;C:/EDI_Module/jar/*;C:/EDI_Module/lib/*; com/solverelogistics/edi/MainGenerator

Can you please tell me what is going on here? I know it runs some app. Which one is the java application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JRE executable (the bytecode interpreter):

```
"C:/EDI_Module/jre1.8.0_121/bin/java"
```

The starting memory size:

```
-Xms2g
```

The maximum memory size:

```
-Xmx10g
```

The [classpath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_(Java)):

```
-cp .;C:/EDI_Module/jar/;C:/EDI_Module/lib/;
```

The class containing a public static void main method to execute:

```
com/solverelogistics/edi/MainGenerator
```

Note: I would have typically expect the class to look something like this `com.solverelogistics.edi.MainGenerator`, with `.`, not `/`.

Comment: One question: cp list is something like including libraries like in C# or it is paths where the Java will be searching for class MainGenerator?

Comment: Edited to add a link to Wikipedia's description of classpath.